# Function errors in python

Tags: python

I am studying python and when I was codding a simple calculator i found this error. **Regardless of the function I call, the operation always adds up**. Someone can help-me?

The code:

class CalculadoraTerminal:

```
# Addition

def addition(add, to_add):
    return add + to_add

# Subtraction

def subtraction(sub, to_sub):
    return sub - to_sub

# Multiplication

def multiplication(multi, to_multi):
    return multi * to_multi

# Division

def division(div, to_div):
    return div / to_div

# Menu

menu = input("A - Addition \nS - Subtraction \nM - Multiplication \nD - Division \nSelect you operation:")

if "A" == menu or "a":
    print(addition(int(input("Type the initial Number: ")), int(input("Type the number to add: "))))

if "S" == menu or "s":
    print(subtraction(int(input("Type the initial number: ")), int(input("Type the number to subtract: "))))

if "M" == menu or "m":
    print(multiplication(int(input("Type the initial number: ")), int(input("Type the number to multiply: "))))

if "D" == menu or "d":
    print(division(int(input("Type the initial  number: ")), int(input("Type the number to divide: "))))
```

Error example:

A - Addition
S - Subtraction
M - Multiplication
**D - Division**
Select you operation:d
Type the initial Number: 20
Type the number to add: 2
22

Comment: ``if menu == "A" or "a":`` does not do what you think it does. same for your other ``if`` statements

Comment: `if menu == "A" or "a"` That is not the right way to check for multiple values.

Comment: You could just test `menu.lower()` against `"a"`

Answer (score 1):

The line `if menu == "A" or "a":` can be rewritten as `if menu == "A"` OR `if 'a'`.

If you want to check if menu is either "A" or "a", please do

```
if menu == "A" or menu == "a":
```